# Azure Managed Instance and Failover / DR Options

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

Azure SQL Managed Instance became generally available on 1-October, 2018. However, I've seen virtually nothing written about what options we have with regards to fail-over and disaster recovery. Specifically I would like to know what happens in the event of a server failure hosting an MI instance. I would also like to know what happens in the event of a data center failure. Does anyone have information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Active Geo-replication is not available in Managed Instance.

**Note:** Active Geo-replication support is coming to public preview very soon.

For more details, refer "[Overview:Active geo-replication and auto-failover groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview)" and "[Setup DR with SQL Managed Instance](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/18251)"

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Geo-replication for Azure SQL Managed Instance is now in public preview.

For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auto-failover-group#best-practices-of-using-failover-groups-with-managed-instances